# How to configure haproxy to use a different backend for each request

Tags: haproxy

I have an Haproxy 1.5.4. I would like to  configure the haproxy to use a different backend for each request. This way , I want to ensure that a diffeent backend is used for each request. I curently use the following config:

```
global
        daemon
    maxconn 500000
    nbproc 2
        log             127.0.0.1   local0 info
defaults
        mode tcp
        timeout connect 50000ms
        timeout client 500000ms
        timeout server 500000ms
        timeout check 5s
        timeout tunnel 50000ms
        option redispatch

listen httptat *:3310
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats refresh 5s
        stats uri /httpstat
        stats realm HTTPS proxy stats
        stats auth https:xxxxxxxxxxx



listen HTTPS *:5008
        mode tcp
        #maxconn 50000

        balance leastconn
server backend1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:125 check
server backend1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:126 check
server backend1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:127 check
server backend1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:128 check
server backend1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:129 check
server backend1 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:130 check

......
```

Answer (score 2):

simply change the balance setting from `leastconn` to `roundrobin`
from the haproxy manual for 1.5 :

**roundrobin** 
 Each server is used in turns, according to their weights.
              This is the smoothest and fairest algorithm when the server's
              processing time remains equally distributed. This algorithm
              is dynamic, which means that server weights may be adjusted
              on the fly for slow starts for instance. It is limited by
              design to 4095 active servers per backend. Note that in some
              large farms, when a server becomes up after having been down
              for a very short time, it may sometimes take a few hundreds
              requests for it to be re-integrated into the farm and start
              receiving traffic. This is normal, though very rare. It is
              indicated here in case you would have the chance to observe
              it, so that you don't worry.

https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#4-balance